# Finitely generated torsional module and Minimal annihlator

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> If A is a finitely generated torsion module, then { $r \in R | rA = 0$ } is a nonzero
> ideal in R, say $(r_1)$. $r_1$ is called the minimal annihilator of A . Let A be a finite
> abelian group with minimal annihilator $m \in \mathbb{Z}$. Show that a cyclic subgroup of A
> of order properly dividing m need not be a direct summand of A.

Attempt: Let on the contrary it be a direct summand of A. So, there exists $A_1,...$ such that $A=A_1 \oplus ...$. Also, A is cyclic but I am not able to understand what result I should use.

I have been doing my masters and following course notes.

Can you please help?

Comment: I'm not sure that a proof by contradiction will work, since the question says that such a subgroup need not be a direct summand, but there's no reason to suspect that some subgroups won't be direct summands. What about $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ for  different $n$ (maybe $n$ as a prime power)?

Comment: @SamJaques Ya, you are right.